# DataGridCellEditEnding event is not firing when I am changing dropdown inside my datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using the following code to use a `ComboBox` inside my `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyHeader" Width="50">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Path=MyVal}" ToolTip="{Binding MyDisplayName}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Width="50" Height="17" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.MyList}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="MyValPath" SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedVal}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyObject}" DisplayMemberPath="MyDisplayName" 
                      FontSize="12"  >
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

`CellTemplate` is for showing my text (custom text for selected value) and `CellEditingTemplate` contains my `ComboBox` which has the actual list.

When I select a value from my drop-down, I have to click on another part of the data grid to get `DataGridDiagnosticCellEditEnding` fired.

I want to get it fired as soon as I select a value or change a value from my `ComboBox`.

I tried adding the following code, but it didn't work:

```
<ComboBox Width="50" Height="17" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.MyList}" 
                                 SelectedValuePath="MyValPath" SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedVal}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyObject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="MyDisplayName" FontSize="12" >
```

Also I tried adding `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`.

Comment: Please only indent by 4 spaces (or more), the code, not the sentences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave a try to your code, and ve got a fix :

1. On the ComboBox of the DataGrid Column, subscribe to the closing event
2. Implement the event Handler and raise a routed Event.

CommitEditCommand belongs to the DataGrid class :

```
    private void ComboBoxDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid.CommitEditCommand.Execute(datagrid1,datagrid1);
    }
```

From there you fall in the DataGrid.CellEditting breakpoint

Here is the working solution : http://1drv.ms/1LFB5Gc

Regards

Comment: If using code behind like this, it's just so simple. You can also use the `CommitEdit()` method of `DataGrid` like this `datagrid1.CommitEdit()`.

Comment: Thank you @Emmanuel for your reply, It resolved the problem by adding dropdownclosed event.

Comment: Than you @King. As i was using code behind i used CommitEdit() method